# Kivmd doesn't seem to recognise MDToolbar

Tags: python, kivymd

I am trying to create an app with toolbar. I am using MDToolbar but I am getting this error:
raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name)
kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class 
Here is my code.

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivymd.uix.snackbar import Snackbar

Window.size = (300, 500)
screen_helper = """
MDNavigationLayout:
    MDToolbar:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "MDNavigationDrawer"
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_bar.set_state('open')], ["clock", lambda x: app.callback_2()],["axe", lambda x: app.callback_1()]]
        on_action_button: app.callback_1(self.icon)
        on_action_button: app.callback_2(self.icon)
    ScreenManager:
```

Comment: Nvm, i solved it. You can just exchange MDToolbar for MDTopAppBar.

Answer (score 4):

Use `MDTopAppBar` instead - https://kivymd.readthedocs.io/en/latest/components/toolbar/ `MDToolbar' has been deprecated since version 1.0.0.